# Flutter Stream Timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter app where I need to get the user location.

I have created a service called LocationService:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_qplan/modelos/user_location.dart';
import 'package:flutter_qplan/servicios/firebase.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class LocationService {
  Location location = Location();
  StreamController<UserLocation> _locationStreamController = StreamController<UserLocation>();
  Stream<UserLocation> get locationStream => _locationStreamController.stream;

  LocationService() {
    location.requestPermission().then((estado_permiso) {
      if (estado_permiso == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        print("permiso esta concedido");
        location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationData) {
          print("@@@@@@@@LocationData:"+locationData.toString());
          if (locationData != null) {
            _locationStreamController.add(UserLocation(
                latitude: locationData.latitude,
                longitude: locationData.longitude));
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        print("permiso no esta concedido");
      }
    });
  }

  void dispose() => _locationStreamController.close();

}
```

Then on a screen I have created a StreamBuilder widget to consume the Stream:

```
body: StreamBuilder<UserLocation>(
          stream: locationService.locationStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              // your code here
              print("UBICACION cambiada");
              latitudData = snapshot.data.latitude;
              longitudData = snapshot.data.longitude;
              Coordinates miscoordenadas = new Coordinates(latitudData, longitudData);
              getAddress(miscoordenadas);
              actualizarUbicacion(latitudData.toString(), longitudData.toString());


            }

            return SafeArea(
...
```

Is there a way to set a period for the Stream, I mean, to get the location every x seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [geolocator package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) you have the possibility to listen to position streaming, as [detailed here](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator/getPositionStream.html), so you don't have to implement it on your own. It is quite simple to add a listener that get's called when user location changes, like this:

```
Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position position) {
...
}
```

In the above listener you will get `position.longitude`, `position.latitude` and also `position.heading`.

To get the current position with a time limit you can do like this:

```
Position? locationData;
try {
      locationData =
          await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(timeLimit: Duration(seconds: 5));
    } on TimeoutException {
      locationData = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
}
```

The last one is useful if for any reason you don't get position data within the timeframe you specified, in this case you can use last known position.

You can pause, resume etc. listening to position, check documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stream.periodic` for that. Below is the basic syntax :

```
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_) {
    // Code returning a value every 2 seconds.
  });
```